# Partitioning N people into N/2 sized groups across N - 1 days

Tags: combinatorics

Problem Statement:

Given a list of $N$ people. On the 1st day, divide them into $N/2$ groups of two people each. On the 2nd day, divide them into groups of two again... Do this every day, until day $N-1$ in a way such that all pairs of people has been groupmates once.

I am not really sure what this problem is called, but here is my solution to it.

Assume $N$ is even and that $N = 2K$

On the 1st day assign the corresponding person from each $K$ sized group to each other:

```
Day1
1 = K+1
2 = K+2
3 = K+3
....
K = 2K
```

On the 2nd day, 1 remains in a fixed position, but every element in the left column moves down (and circles to the right) 1 slot and every element in the right column moves up 1 slot (circles to the left under 1).

```
Day2
1   = K+2
K+1 = K+3
2   = K+4
3   = K+5
....
K-1 = K
```

This continues until Day $N-1$ and at that point all the people have been grouped once.

Small example $N = 6$ $K = 3$:

```
Day1      Day2        Day3        Day4       Day5(N-1)
1 = K+1   1   = K+2   1   = K+3   1   = K    1   = 2
2 = K+2   K+1 = K+3   K+2 = K     K+3 = 2    K   = K+1
K = K+3   2   = K     K+1 = 2     K+2 = K+1  K+3 = K+2
```

Questions:

1. What is this type of problem classified as?
2. Is there a simpler solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are essentially finding automorphisms of of a cycle graph on $n$ vertices. An automorphism is an isomorphism from a graph (or group) onto itself. There are $n$ such automorphisms for the graph $C_{n}$. You are, of course, excluding the identity automorphism.

You could equivocally think of this as a bipartite matching problem. I think looking at this as an automorphism is a better way to look at it though.

Comment: Sorry for my extremely delayed response, thanks for this. This lead to some other interesting readings when I expanded my search.

Comment: Glad I could help! :-)